# Pytest : breakpoint() don't stop the test execution

Tags: python, pytest, pdb

I'm fairly new to Pytest, and I guess I'm missing something obvious here.

When I set a `breakpoint()` in my application code, and then launch my tests with `pytest`, the breakpoint is showing in my console, I start to debug, but the test continue in the background and after a few seconds it stops my debugger and displays the test result. Super frustrating.

The breakpoint works as expected if I set it up in the test code, the problem occurs only in the application code.

I tried a few configuration options in `pytest.ini`, like

```
timeout = 0
faulthandler_timeout = 0
```

but it don't change anything. What am I missing ?